# Replace Values in Column Based on values in a list in Pandas with nan without using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe.
`test = {'x': [1.1, 1.2, 0.15, 20], 'y': [-111, -20, -1.9, -80]} df = pd.DataFrame(test)`

I also have another list which contains some numbers, `ls=[1.2, 0.15, 2.2]`. I would like to replace element in "x" columns of df which has same values as "ls" with nan. Therefore, I write using for loop.

```
for i in ls:
    df.loc[df['x'] == i, 'x'] = np.nan
```

I would like to know whether there are other way to achieve the same purpose without using for loop to replace some values in dataframe with nan?

Expected output:
| Index | x  | y   |
|:----- |:---|:--- |
|0.     |1.1 |-111 |
|1.     |nan |-20. |
|2.     |nan |-1.9 |
|3.     |20. |-80. |

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
df.loc[df['x'].isin(ls), 'x'] = np.nan
```

Another idea with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['x'] = df['x'].mask(df['x'].isin(ls))
```

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use `where` here? Like `df.x.where(~df.x.isin(ls), pd.NA)`

Comment: @JustJames - I think better is mask, not necessary invert mask `df['x'] = df['x'].mask(df['x'].isin(ls))`